# Java Play 2.4 write test case for class using injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework-2.4

Recently I am using play 2.4 framework for Java project.

In that I am using WsClient Library. That library is injected in my class.

```
@Inject WSClient wsClient
```

Now I am trying to write a test case for that class but test case fails because of null pointer error for wsClient variable.

```
wsClient.url("some url").get()
```

Can you please help me to resolve this?

following is the test code

```
// Class
public class ElasticSearch {
  @Inject WSClient wsClient;

  public Promise<WSResponse> createIndex() {
        Logger.info("Entering ElasticSearch.createIndex()");
        Logger.debug("WSClient: " + wsClient);
        Promise<WSResponse> response =wsClient.url(this.getEsClient()+ "/" +this.getEsIndexName()).setContentType("application/json").put("");
        Logger.info("Exiting ElasticSearch.createIndex()");
        return response;
    }
}


// Test function
 @Test
public void testCreateIndex() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ElasticSearch esearch= new ElasticSearch();
            esearch.setEsIndexName("car_model");
            assertNotNull(esearch.createIndex());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the test code?

Comment: Hi Tomer, 
Thanks for your reply, I have modified question and added test code.

Comment: Do you want to test elasticsearch functionality? meaning do you load an actual elasticsearch cluster and want to query it? or you want to "mock" the retuned results from the wsClinet?

Comment: I want to test ElasticSearch class functionality that I have created. I am sending calls to ElasticSearch DB using WSClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before writing the options you have, I suggest to use [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s).
This third party lib will help you write a more functional code and give you very nice dsl to write your queries.
One more thing, I don't know what is your used case for using elasticsearch, but I recommend using a different client then the rest api, which will give you more secure connection and more efficient.

You get the NPE, because you instasiate ElasticSearch by your own with new, and don't let guice to the wiring for you, this is why the WSClient is null.

Now for your options, 
You have 2 options:

Add WithApplication to your test, which will basically load your application, this will give you the access to Guice injector, from which you can take ElasticSearch class like this you have couple of ways to do it:

1. As described in play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice) using

   ```
        import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjectorBuilder
        import play.api.inject.bind
        val injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder()
        .configure("key" -> "value")
        .bindings(new ComponentModule)
        .overrides(bind[Component].to[MockComponent])
        .injector

        val elasticsearch = injector.instanceOf[ElasticSearch]
   ```
2. By importing Play

   ```
        import play.api.Play 
        val elasticsearch = Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[ElasticSearch])
   ```
3. Using FakeApplication: just get hold of the fake application injector, and use it to get an instance of ElasticSearch class.

I don't like the above options, because you need an application running, which can make your tests very slow.
I suggest to create the WSClient by your self and instantiate ElasticSearch class with it, and run your tests.

```
val httpClient = NingWSClient.apply()
val elasticsearch = new ElasticSearch(httpClient)
```

This is a more light solution, and should make your tests run faster.